# How to use Pub/sub with hiredis in C++?

Tags: redis

I am trying to test this pub/sub function of redis with hiredis client via c++.

I can see that subscribing to certain channel seems to be easy enough to do through redisCommand Api.

However I am wondering how the reply is coming back when somebody publish to the certain server.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/redis/hiredis/issues/55
aluiken commented on Mar 2, 2012

```
void onMessage(redisAsyncContext *c, void *reply, void *privdata) {
    redisReply *r = reply;
    if (reply == NULL) return;

    if (r->type == REDIS_REPLY_ARRAY) {
        for (int j = 0; j < r->elements; j++) {
            printf("%u) %s\n", j, r->element[j]->str);
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    struct event_base *base = event_base_new();

    redisAsyncContext *c = redisAsyncConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
    if (c->err) {
        printf("error: %s\n", c->errstr);
        return 1;
    }

    redisLibeventAttach(c, base);
    redisAsyncCommand(c, onMessage, NULL, "SUBSCRIBE testtopic");
    event_base_dispatch(base);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a late answer, but you can try [redis-plus-plus](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus), which is based on hiredis, and written in C++ 11.

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of this library. If you have any problem with this client, feel free to [let me know](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/issues). If you like it, also feel free to [star it](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus) :)

Sample code:

```
Redis redis("tcp://127.0.0.1:6379");

// Create a Subscriber.
auto sub = redis.subscriber();

// Set callback functions.
sub.on_message([](std::string channel, std::string msg) {
    // Process message of MESSAGE type.
});

sub.on_pmessage([](std::string pattern, std::string channel, std::string msg) {
    // Process message of PMESSAGE type.
});

sub.on_meta([](Subscriber::MsgType type, OptionalString channel, long long num) {
    // Process message of META type.
});

// Subscribe to channels and patterns.
sub.subscribe("channel1");
sub.subscribe({"channel2", "channel3"});

sub.psubscribe("pattern1*");

// Consume messages in a loop.
while (true) {
    try {
        sub.consume();
    } catch (...) {
        // Handle exceptions.
    }
}
```

Check the [doc](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus#publishsubscribe) for detail.

Answer (score 0):

Observer pattern is what we see in pub/sub feature of Redis.

All subscribers are observers and subject is the channel which is being modified by publishers.

When a publisher modifies a channel i.e. executes command like redis-cli> publish foo value
This change is communicated by Redis server to all observers (i.e. subscribers)

So Redis server has list of all observers for a particular channel.